# jquery fadeToggle use visibility instead of display

Tags: jquery, css, visibility, fade

I currently am using `jQuery("#addCaseMemberBtn").fadeToggle( "fast" );` but it is causing content to jump up/down when it completes because it is using `display`. How can I tell it to use `visibility` or accomplish the same thing with visibility so that the content does not jump.

Comment: You may want to re-think your accepted answer since it relies on a jQuery function that was removed several versions ago.

Comment: Sorry, I accepted the answer before anything was added. I am not a jQuery dev so I do not know functions that have been removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could toggle the opacity with animate():

```js
$("button").click(function () {
    $("p:first").animate({opacity:($("p:first").css('opacity')==1)?0:1});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>fadeToggle p1</button>
<p>This paragraph has a slow, linear fade.</p>
<p>This paragraph has no animation.</p>
```

Comment: Yes, look at the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/znhqkjj1/) - it doesn't work like toggle

Comment: @r4xz - How doesn't it? Please be more specific.

Comment: When the opacity is < 1 then it'll always call "fadeIn". Change your animate() to fadeToggle() and see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.animate()` and play with the `visibility`:

```js
$(function () {
    $('#addCaseMemberBtn').animate({
        visibility: hidden
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
#addCaseMemberBtn {
    background-color: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="addCaseMemberBtn"></div>
```

[.animate() | jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)